# Add columns to existing select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have a pre-formed Zend_Db_Select which already utilized `columns()` method.
I need to add another column to select. Executing `columns()` again replaces the previous one, so I lose the previously selected columns.
Modifying the select I recieve is not possible.

How to add another column to an existing Zend_Db_Select which already incorporates `columns()` method? Is it possible without parts surgery?